# Can I Use Processing 3 For Loop with If Statement for Animation Frames?

Tags: animation, if-statement, for-loop, processing, lerp

Script runs in Processing 3.0.1 editor. I want to achieve:

- continuous loop
- maintain for loop's value of 10 (where each new set of triangles in for loop replaces each oldest set making the animation appear as a
  flaming meteor)

Can I accomplish this with a simple if statement, or do I need to create an array, or...? Open to suggestions.

```java
void setup() {
  size(504, 282);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {
  color from = color(255, 0, 0, 50);
  color to   = color(255, 255, 0, 300);
  color a = lerpColor(from, to, .33);
  color b = lerpColor(from, to, .66);
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    // 1st Stage
    float a1=random(0, 84);
    float b1=random(0, 47);
    float c1=random(84, 168);
    float d1=random(47, 94);
    float e1=random(168, 252);
    float f1=random(94, 141);
    fill(from);
    triangle(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1);
    // 2nd Stage
    float a2=random(84, 168);
    float b2=random(47, 94);
    float c2=random(168, 252);
    float d2=random(94, 141);
    float e2=random(252, 336);
    float f2=random(141, 188);
    fill(a);
    triangle(a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2);
    // 3rd Stage
    float a3=random(168, 252);
    float b3=random(94, 141);
    float c3=random(252, 336);
    float d3=random(141, 188);
    float e3=random(336, 420);
    float f3=random(188, 235);
    fill(b);
    triangle(a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3);
    // 4th Stage
    float a4=random(252, 336);
    float b4=random(141, 188);
    float c4=random(336, 420);
    float d4=random(188, 235);
    float e4=random(420, 504);
    float f4=random(235, 282);
    fill(to);
    triangle(a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4);
    noStroke();
  }
  //saveFrame("####.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Create a **class** that encapsulates everything you need to know to draw a single "stage". For you, this might be the points on your triangle.

**Step 2**: Create an `ArrayList` that holds instances of that class.

**Step 3**: In your `draw()` function, create instances of that class and add it to your `ArrayList`. You can use the `frameCount` variable with the `mod` operator to control the "speed" of your animation.

**Step 4**: When the `ArrayList` contains more than 10 objects, remove the first one to get rid of the oldest one.

**Step 5**: Loop through your objects and draw them.

Putting it all together, it might look something like this (with your shapes instead of a rectangle:

```java
ArrayList<MyShape> shapes = new ArrayList<MyShape>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (MyShape shape : shapes) {
    shape.draw();
  }

  if (frameCount % 10 == 0) {
    shapes.add(new MyShape());

    if (shapes.size() >= 10) {
      shapes.remove(0);
    }
  }
}

class MyShape {

  float x;
  float y;
  float r;

  public MyShape() {
    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
    r = random(10, 20);
  }

  public void draw() {
    rect(x, y, r, r);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

background() function clears buffer for each new frame when it is placed in draw() function.

```
void setup() {
  size(504, 282);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  color from = color(255, 0, 0, 50);
  color to   = color(255, 255, 0, 300);
  color a = lerpColor(from, to, .33);
  color b = lerpColor(from, to, .66);
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    float a1=random(0, 84);
    float b1=random(0, 47);
    float c1=random(84, 168);
    float d1=random(47, 94);
    float e1=random(168, 252);
    float f1=random(94, 141);
    fill(from);
    triangle(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1);
    float a2=random(84, 168);
    float b2=random(47, 94);
    float c2=random(168, 252);
    float d2=random(94, 141);
    float e2=random(252, 336);
    float f2=random(141, 188);
    fill(a);
    triangle(a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2);
    float a3=random(168, 252);
    float b3=random(94, 141);
    float c3=random(252, 336);
    float d3=random(141, 188);
    float e3=random(336, 420);
    float f3=random(188, 235);
    fill(b);
    triangle(a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3);
    float a4=random(252, 336);
    float b4=random(141, 188);
    float c4=random(336, 420);
    float d4=random(188, 235);
    float e4=random(420, 504);
    float f4=random(235, 282);
    fill(to);
    triangle(a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4);
    noStroke();
  }
}
```